# dc.js to plot line chart, How to break line if data is not present

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a requirement to make a line chart by using dc.js. hourly basis some amount will be plotted. my concern is to break the line if on that particular hour no data has come. suppose, 12 hour , no data has come .. so upto 11th hour line will show. and from 13th hours, the line will be shown again based on data availability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be possible to break the line in line chart, by not displaying the particular line in that period.

Using 
`.defined(function(d) { return d.responseTime != -120;})` function of d3.

Comment: Wow, that is very cool. They have thought of everything in d3. Where did you add this to make it work? Here is the link, for anyone looking: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29020499/1396904) for a code example

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this isn't supported.

It's generally not considered a good practice to use a line chart for discontinuous data - a bar chart is more appropriate.  However, as this is often requested, feel free to [open an enhancement request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your answer, But after a lot of R&D to match my requirement , finally I find the solution.. please my answer. Thanks