# dc/d3 line chart crashing down to 0 on the y axis after filtering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

When I apply a dimension filter to a dc.js graph, there are ugly lines where the line plummets 
towards the y axis.

[image: Sample screenshot]

Is it possible in dc/d3 to not do this, i.e I would expect the graph to more resemble the following;

[image: Desired]

Comment: Well it draws the data that you give it. If you want it to omit certain parts, don't give it the data for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `defined` directly on the dc created chart.

```
chart
  .chart((c) ->
    dc.lineChart(c)
      .interpolate('linear')
      .defined((d) ->
        return !isNaN(d.y)
      )
  )
```

The condition `!isNan(d.y)` can be anything you like that evaluates to true/false.

Note that the `d` passed by `defined` is a d3 object and is worth inspecting.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions, depending whether you want the line connected or in sections:

1. Pre-filter the data so that instead of having groups that sum to zero, there aren't groups there at all. This will connect the points with a line segment over the missing data. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted
2. Use `lineChart.defined` to put gaps/breaks in the line where there is no data. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#definedvalue