# dc.js line chart breaking and dropping to 0 on 'null' values in the dimension

Tags: linechart, dc.js, crossfilter

This is my first Stackoverflow question and I am a little nervous but this has been bugging me for a while now and I can't sort a fix or workaround. I think this question is related to this one

[dc/d3 line chart crashing down to 0 on the y axis after filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413683/dc-d3-line-chart-crashing-down-to-0-on-the-y-axis-after-filtering/24421957#24421957)

but I have gone into a bit more detail, have a jsfiddle to show the problem and am not sure that the suggested solutions to the above question will solve my problem.

I am plotting a line chart on a dimension I have filtered when reducing to remove values I do not want to include on the plot (please see this jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/hldawe/62tuq30o/

```
var facts = crossfilter(datajson);


var testlineChart = dc.lineChart('#testlinechart');

var expectedDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {
   return d.expected;
});

var observedGroup = expectedDim.group().reduce(

function reduceAdd(p, v) {
   if (v.expected % v.expected === 0 && v.indicator_code === "MH998") {
       p += +v.observed;
   }
   return p;
},

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
   if (v.expected % v.expected === 0 && v.indicator_code === "MH998") {
       p -= -v.observed;
}
return p;
},

function reduceInitial() {
 return 0;
});

testlineChart.width(500)
 .height(220)
 .dimension(expectedDim)
 .group(observedGroup)
 .brushOn(true)
 .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]))
 .xAxis();

dc.renderAll();
```

Despite this removal when reducing, the line chart is still bottoming out to zero on those values that have been removed! I would just like a continuous line and I think that's how it should be using the grouping I have done? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, have you tried `lineChart.defined`? https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#definedvalue

Comment: Hi Gordon many thanks for your help. Using .defined I have managed to get rid of the zeros but now have breaks in the line. This is an improvement but I would like to join the line up.

Comment: Sorry meant to add that here is my updated jsfiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/hldawe/62tuq30o/

Comment: Ok sorry again here is my updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hldawe/62tuq30o/ I will keep trying to join the line up but I am new to dc and crossfilter so if you have any clues they would be most welcome thank you again :o)

Comment: Ah, in that case you want option number 1 in my  answer to the question you cited. You need to entirely drop the points that you don't want. (However, I think it may be a bit dishonest to use a line chart in this instance because it implies that the data is continuous. But I don't know your application.)

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks again for your reply. I do need a line chart in this instance as I am building a statistical process control chart and the line being plotted is a control limit. The other points in the JSON are discrete values I wish to test for being above or below the control limit. As in drawing the chart I am testing the hypothesis that the expected value (always continuous) compared to the observed value (always discrete) are the same, this is perhaps where the 'dishonesty' comes in. I have updated my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hldawe/62tuq30o/ and it now shows a composite chart...

Comment: ... that has the line with a scatterplot superimposed. This is the bare bones of the control chart I am trying to plot. When I try to filter as you suggest I either drop the points or the line or both! If I have come up against something logically wrong here then I will need to change tack but I am not yet sure I have! Any thoughts you have on this are most welcome. Many thanks again Heather

Comment: Got it. Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems to me you want an expected group on the expected dimension (as well as the observed group on the observed dimension). Then you can "filter out" the 0s before they are plotted by using this bit of code from the FAQ I pointed to in the other answer:

```
var expectedGroup2 = {
   all:function () {
    return expectedGroup.all().filter(function(d) {
      return d.value != 0;
    })
   }
};
```

Do this somewhere before creating the line chart, and use `expectedGroup2` instead of `expectedGroup`. The idea is that this is a live object which screens out empty bins from the group as they are read. (It is entirely different from a filter in the crossfilter sense.)

Comment: Hi Gordon, that is great it is working now thank you so much for your help and for putting up with my noobie questions. dc.js and crossfilter are great :o)

Comment: Glad to help! This technique is a bit tricky and probably belongs in a helper library.