# Drawing gaps for missing dates in dc.js time series line graph

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Okay, so I've seen [this](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/615) ticket and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413683/dc-d3-line-chart-crashing-down-to-0-on-the-y-axis-after-filtering/29020499#29020499) question and have tried several examples already.  Maybe I'm just dense, but I really haven't been able to crack this one.

I have a time series of events that has gaps in it.  By default, dc.js connects a straight line over the gap (making it look like things are represented there when they really shouldn't be).  For example, in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mater_tua/QD9Ev/) graph we have data as follows:

```
    {"time":"2014-06-09T18:45:00.000Z","input":17755156,"output":250613233.333333},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T18:46:00.000Z","input":18780286.6666667,"output":134619822.666667},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T18:47:00.000Z","input":20074614.6666667,"output":203239834.666667},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T18:48:00.000Z","input":22955373.3333333,"output":348996205.333333},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T18:49:00.000Z","input":19119089.3333333,"output":562631022.666667},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T18:50:00.000Z","input":15404272,"output":389916332},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T18:51:00.000Z","input":null,"output":null},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T21:25:20.000Z","input":5266038.66666667,"output":62598396},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T21:26:20.000Z","input":6367678.66666667,"output":84494096},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T21:27:20.000Z","input":5051610.66666667,"output":88812540},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T21:28:20.000Z","input":5761069.33333333,"output":79098036},
    {"time":"2014-06-09T21:29:20.000Z", "input":5110277.33333333,"output":45816729.3333333}
```

Even though there's only two actual groups of data, there's a line on that graph connecting them.  How do I make dc.js line graphs draw 0 where there is no data at all.  I've tried using `.defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.x);})` and `.defined(function(d) { return d.y != null; })` and such, but this is just iterating through data which isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky trying to preserve nulls when using crossfilter, because crossfilter is all about aggregation.

Remember that `reduceSum` will add any values it finds, starting from zero, and `0 + null === 0`.

In your case, it looks like you're not actually aggregating, since your timestamps are unique, so you could do something like this:

```
var input  = time.group().reduce(
    function(p, d) {
       if(d.input !== null)
           p += d.input;
       else p = null;
       return p;
    },
    function(p, d) {
       if(d.input !== null)
           p -= d.input;
       else p = null;
       return p;
    },
    function(){ return 0; }
);
```

Yeah, that's a lot more complicated than `reduceSum`, and it may get even more complicated if more than one datum falls into a bucket. (Not sure what you'd want to do there - is it possible for a data point to be partly defined?)

With the reduction defined this way, null reduces to null and dc.js is able to find the gaps:
[image: line chart with gaps]

Fork of your fiddle (thanks!): http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/omLko77k/3/

#### Edit: counting nulls

If you're doing a "real" reduction where there is more than one value in a bin, I think you'll need to count the number of non-null values as well as keeping a running sum.

When there are no non-null values, the sum should be `null`.

Reusing our code a bit better this time:

```
function null_counter(field) {
    return {
        add: function(p, d) {
            if(d[field] !== null) {
                p.nvalues++;
                p.sum += d[field];
            }
            return p;
        },
        remove: function(p, d) {
            if(d[field] !== null) {
                p.nvalues--;
                p.sum -= d[field];
                if(!p.nvalues)
                    p.sum = null;
            }
            return p;
        },
        init: function() {
            return {nvalues: 0, sum: null};
        }
    }
}
```

Applied like this (and getting the fields right this time):

```
var input_reducer = null_counter('input');
var input = time.group().reduce(
    input_reducer.add,
    input_reducer.remove,
    input_reducer.init
);
var output_reducer = null_counter('output');
var output = time.group().reduce(
    output_reducer.add,
    output_reducer.remove,
    output_reducer.init
);
```

Since we're reducing to an object with two values `{nvalues, sum}`, we need to make all our accessors a little more complicated:

```
    .valueAccessor(function(kv) { return kv.value.sum; })
    .defined(function(d){
        return (d.data.value.sum !== null);
    })
chart.stack(output, "Output bits",
            function(kv) { return kv.value.sum; });
```

Updated fork: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/omLko77k/9/

Comment: Gordon, after pouring over all the other StackOverflow questions you've answered I was really hoping you'd show up here!

Comment: Any suggestions on how I would aggregate in the event my timestamps aren't unique (example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ta3khggy/2/)?  I've ran into this problem on multiple fronts.  Thanks for all your help and the work you guys do on the framework!

Comment: I'll think about it and revise my answer tomorrow. I guess the best thing to do is *any number of nulls* -> `null`; *any numbers* -> *ignore the nulls and add the numbers*. I think that means you have to count the nulls. :-(

Comment: Got around to updating with a null-counter, or rather a non-null counter. Hope it is not too late, please let me know if it works.

Comment: It's definitely not too late; I kept at it and wasn't able to piece together a better solution.  I'll try it out later this week/end and let you know how it goes!

Comment: This works somewhat, but it doesn't quite solve my problem.  Unless I'm mistaken, the method you presented requires me to know where the gaps will lie in advance (http://jsfiddle.net/ta3khggy/4/).  In real life, the data comes from an API and I don't really know where (or if) gaps will be ahead of time.   Additionally, this method seems to totally obfuscate "islands" of data (http://jsfiddle.net/ta3khggy/6/). I can get around this if I draw empty dates as a 0 (http://jsfiddle.net/ta3khggy/7/), but this still requires me to know empty dates in advance so I can fake the data.

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood because you have nulls for missing data in your example. Do you know the resolution of your data in advance, i.e. do you know that the data should come in every second and if it doesn't that's a gap? How would you represent a single "island" datum, as a point? I can think of a decent way to solve the first problem but the second would probably require some hack.

Comment: Yes, I can make sure the data always comes through in the same resolution and anything missing can be considered a gap.  Ideally island data would be shown like this (http://jsfiddle.net/ta3khggy/7/), though a point could work as well.  It seems like it might be easier (though hacky) to just iterate through the data and fill in the gaps with fake zeros.

Comment: Oh, you actually want it to drop to zero instead of using `.defined()` to make the lines discontinuous? Okay, I misunderstood that too. You can use a fake group to fill in the gaps with nulls or zeros, as you prefer. Slightly less hacky than changing the input data, maybe. I could hack up an example if you're interested. I don't think I've covered this before.

Comment: I could go either way-- really it just needs to be made clear to the user that there is no data (or it sums to zero, which is the same in my case) for missing dates.  If a fake group can fill in the gaps with zeros, that seems like the way to go since that already effectively handles data islands.